# How to fix microsoft repo downloads being slow for apt upgrade?

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, repository, download

**Intro**:
I'm running into an issue while upgrading my installed packages with apt, and I'm curious whether you have an idea where to start resolving my issue, because I'm afraid I don't. I'm surprised to see that searching for my issue on google.com/startpage.com does not give me any useful results, so I guess nobody else is experiencing it.

**The issue:**
Upgrading packages installed through microsoft repo's in apt is incredibly slow due to an incredibly slow download speed of 60kB/s, whereas I don't even notice any other packages downloading (such as signal-desktop, which is similar in size to teams/vscode updates). I have a very quick internet connection of >= 600Mbps up/down, so that can't be the issue.

EDIT: The repos that I download the updates from are configured automatically during installation of the .deb packages from the website: http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code and https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams . In my /etc/apt/sources the distribution and configuration for both of these are configured as 'stable main'.

**Question:**
Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which _precise_ repo? The simplest hypothesis is that they dislike your IP address for whatever reason and throttle your download speed. Try using a proxy to at least test whether this changes anything.

Comment: if the repository is set to be slow (which appears to be the case at least today), there's nothing much you can do. If you have to download multiple times the same package from it (for a farm of systems), search for Q/A about local caching proxies (eg using apt-cacher-ng which wouldn't be trivial to adapt with https but can do it)

Comment: In case the repo has a country code in the domain, you might try changing that.

Comment: @tripleee I've updated the details to answer your question, thanks for the clarification request. Do you know a trust-worthy proxy I can try easily? I haven't used a proxy before.

Comment: I don't have any recommendations, there seems to be a lot of sites with free open proxies but I can't vouch for any particular one.

Comment: @tripleee Using a VPN resolved the issue, so it indeed seems they dislike my IP address for whatever reason. Thanks the help everyone! I'm going to try and reach out to MIcrosoft support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact cause of the issue is still unknown right now, but as @tripleee suggested, using a VPN/proxy resolved the issue:
I used AirVPN with a server also in the Netherlands and this resolved the issue, so it seems it is related to my IP address.